# ruby on rails, no route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have just started using ruby on rails, using rubymine package and following a tutorial.

We have created a controller called `say` as follows:

```
class SayController < ApplicationController
  def Hello
  end
end
```

I start the rails server and get the page on `localhost:3000`, but when I try `localhost:3000/say/hello`, I get:

```
No route matches [GET] "/say/hello"
```

I tried to change the file `routes.rb` inside `config` to:

```
root 'say#index'
```

But no joy, still the same error.I hope I have given enough info, thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you have following at your `routes.rb`:

```
root 'say#index'
```

that tells rails that when user visits `/` it invokes `say` controllers `index` action. But since you want `/say/hello` route to invoke 'say#index' then your `routes.rb` should have something like this:

```
get '/say/hello', to: 'say#Hello'
```

If you are on window and getting `ExecJS::ProgramError` then either you can replace "application" with "default" of your `application.html.erb` or You can do this at your Gemfile: gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0' to force 1.8.0 and then issue bundle update coffee-script-source. coffee-script source >= 1.9.0 don't work properly under Windows.

Comment: I tried your suggestions and got:    The action 'index' could not be found for SayController

Comment: do you have index method in SayController?

Comment: No only hello : but I get this error when I use hello instead of root 'say#index' : ExecJS::ProgramError in Say#hello. Must I have both get and root defined within routes.rb?

Comment: root definite your '/' route and get '/say/hello' defines what controller method to call when that link is visited. So it is not mandatory to define both. You can only define which one is necessary.

Comment: you need to have a index method at SayController and a index.html.erb, if you use "say#index"

Comment: I have a hello.html.erb in views>say folder and put this inside routes.rb     get '/say/hello' => 'say#hello'
root 'say#hello' .  Do I still need to use root delcaration or is 'get' enough? Thanks.

Comment: You don't need root declaration.

Comment: Then at I am at my wits end as I get this error: ExecJS::ProgramError in Say#hello

Comment: can you post your hello.html.erb?

Comment: and application.html.erb

Comment: <h1>say#hello</h1>   # hello.html.erb                                                              and application.html.erb  :              <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>FirstTry</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>

Comment: at application.html.erb replace "application" with "default"

Comment: WOW !! worked :). I am afraid I do not have enough points to give you a thumbs up. So why this is the case? Thanks a lot.

Comment: There is a tick mark just beside my answer, below the arrows of vote count. Just click on that tick, if you click on that tick then the answer will be accepted and you and me both will both receive few reputation increase.

Answer (score 0):

First thing: refactor your `hello` method to be all lower case as follow:

```
class SayController < ApplicationController
  def hello
  end
end
```

Now to answer your question:

The route file is like a guide, which maps given routes `host/path/options` to given controller methods. `root 'say#index'` where `say` is your controller and `index` is the method in the specified controller.

For example, taking the route you have as an instance,

```
root 'say#index'
```

means to make the `index` action of the `say` controller the default route.(on page load)

> Note however that you don't even have any `index` action in your `SayController` yet

Saying this, it means that to get the `hello` action you have in your `SayController` as the default route, you need to do something as this:

```
root 'say#hello'
```

And then, when you go to `localhost:3000`, you get your page.

And on the other hand, if you don't want it as the root, you just need to specify the kind of `http` method it will support ( `get`, `post`, `put` or `delete`) as follow:

```
get '/say/hello' => 'say#hello'
```

Now, when you go to `localhost:300/say/hello` you get your page.

Hope this is well explanatory enough...

Comment: I tried this and got:    Missing template say/hello, application/hello with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "C:/Users/new-pc/RubymineProjects/first-try/app/views"

Comment: Okay, that is good. It means that your route worked. So, what you have to do now is to follow the error code. Like it said, ` no template`. so, create a file named according to your controller action(`hello.html.erb`) inside the `view` directory of your app, and put whatever content you want ( put say `"hello world"` for example. And you should see the "Hello World" when you refresh your page.

Comment: I added hello.html.erb to view with a <h1 say#hello <h1> got error: object does not support this property or method:                             <head>
    <title>FirstTry</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>
  <body>

Comment: This is  my sayController: class SayController < ApplicationController
  def hello
  end
end  and there is a hello.html.erb file inside the views->say folder plus what I used inside routes.rb

Comment: Wait, are you following any tutorial at all?

Comment: about 29 lectures in this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6FYtGYPUG-E&index=8&list=PLSXDqiI4sC5PsASjJy7dBncALnhjud2fx